# Mapping tons of printers

Tags: windows, printing, server, powershell-4.0

Can you help me understand why this script wont work?
I need to map tons of printers

```
$path = 'C:\temp\printers.csv'
Import-Csv -Header ('Printernames') -Path $path
foreach ($Printer in $Printername) {
    start \\print01\$Printer
}
```

It's Looks like it takes the header of the CSV file within everytime it loops.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Import-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) cmdlet automatically reads the first line of the input file as the CSV headers. The `-Header` parameter exists so you can provide custom headers in case your data file comes without headers.

**Example:**

Consider a file `input.csv` with the following content:

```
1,"a",23
2,"b",42
```

If you read that file normally, the first line would be interpreted as the headers of the CSV:

```
PS C:\> Import-Csv 'input.csv'

1    a    23
-    -    --
2    b    42
```

To import all rows as data rows you provide custom headers via the parameter `-Header`:

```
PS C:\> Import-Csv 'input.csv' -Header A,B,C

A    B    C
-    -    -
1    a    23
2    b    42
```

Comment: PrinterNames
E14-Leasing
E14-Pladen
E2-Adm-01

Comment: Where printernames is the only header, and printer names is in the row. 
Still get the header in output.

Comment: @MartinBarbesgaardHansen Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40018078/edit) your question and show a representative sample of your input file.